# In dynet, can I save a model in a compressed file?

Tags: python, compression, data-science

In dynet, [it is possible to save a model to a text file](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_saving_tutorial.html).
When I save my model, it is over 40 MB. I save 100 models in a single run, which is 4 GB.

Is there a way to save a model in a compressed format, so that it does not take so much disk space?

Comment: @DRPK I am not talking about the py files - they are quite small. I am talking about the text files that are created by doing "model.save(filename)". These files are huge.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, but there is an [issue](https://github.com/clab/dynet/issues/648) about it.
Of course, you can zip the files and unzip them later:

After `save(filename, ...)`:

```
import zipfile
from glob import glob
import os
files = glob(filename + ".*")
with zipfile.ZipFile(filename + ".zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zh:
    for fname in files:
        zh.write(fname)
for fname in files:
    os.remove(fname)
```

Before `load(filename)`:

```
import zipfile
import os
with zipfile.ZipFile(filename + ".zip", "r") as zh:
    zh.extractall(os.path.dirname(filename))
os.remove(filename + ".zip")
```